# In python, I want to extract text data

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get text from web page right now, but, after I got the web page URL, I'm having a hard time to move on to next because I don't know how to deal with BeautifulSoup

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.dom.minidom

keyWord = raw_input("Enter the key-word : ")
address = "http://openapi.naver.com/search?key=c1b406b32dbbbbeee5f2a36ddc14067f&query=" + keyWord + "&display=5&start=1&target=kin&sort=sim"
search_result = urllib.urlopen(address)
raw_data = search_result.read()

parsed_result = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(raw_data)
links = parsed_result.getElementsByTagName('link')

extracted_URL = links[0].firstChild.nodeValue
page = urllib.urlopen(extracted_URL).read()
```

Comment: have a look here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start

Comment: "I want text but I don't know how to deal with BeautifulSoup" isn't a question anyone here can help you with. Have you read a tutorial or documentation? What text are you trying to get?

Comment: one big problem is that you didn't even ask a question. what is your problem? what have you done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize a [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup) object with `xml` markup:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

keyWord = raw_input("Enter the key-word : ")
address = "http://openapi.naver.com/search?key=c1b406b32dbbbbeee5f2a36ddc14067f&query=" + keyWord + "&display=5&start=1&target=kin&sort=sim"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(address), 'xml')
print [link.text for link in soup.find_all('link')]
```

prints (for the `test` keyword):

```
[u'http://search.naver.com', 
 u'http://openapi.naver.com/l?AAAA3IOQ6AIBRF0dVIaQQUq1/YuA+GRzDECb8m7F5uTnXvF6US42HB9QLl7RAZlbx042CcVsG1AExRWW1C8LL9OYpUECkxX51eOrU2D2zxqT/sh9L7c/8BHpFL8lsAAAA=',
 ...
]
```

Also, it's worth going through [Quick Start](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) chapter in docs.

Hope that helps.